# how can i run broadcastreceiver without stoping?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to run broadcastreceiver without stoping and i dont know how.

I do not know if there is service runs all the time...

Thnaks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to start/stop a BroadcastReceiver. Its not your background running service. All you need is to register or unregister it for your application. Once registered, its always ON.

When some specific event occur, system notifies(broadcast) all registered applications about the event. all registered apps receives this as an `Intent`. Also, you can send your own broadcast.

for more, [see this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Simple Example:

in my manifest, I'm including a permission and a receiver

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.android.receivercall"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver android:name=".Main">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity android:name=".TelServices">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Now, my receiver, **Main.java**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;



   public class Main extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String number,state;   
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         state=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
            number=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

            Toast.makeText(context, "Call from : "+number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
            Toast.makeText(context, "Call ended", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(context, intent.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

Here, when I install this app, I'm registering a Broadcastreceiver through manifest. And the Toast will appear every time a call comes/ends.